# In C++, how can I construct a 'per-input parameter' singleton?

Tags: c++

In `MyClass`, if I have this singleton pattern. If I call

```cpp
MyClass<MyInputClass>::getInstance("a");
MyClass<MyInputClass>::getInstance("b");
MyClass<MyInputClass>::getInstance("c");
```

Seems, the constructor (where it prints the input) is only called the first time. Is this the static keyword at work?

What I want to achieve is:

I want to make the string input optional, so that if there's no string input, then it will have a single instance per MyInputClass (eg a child class of MyInputClass).

But there's another use case in which for the same MyInputClass, I want a different instance per input if input is not null.

```
public:
static MyClass<MyInputClass>& getInstance(std::string input){
       static MyClass<MyInputClass> instance(input);
       return instance;
    };

explicit MyClass(parameter){       
        std::cout<<parameter<<std::endl;   
    }
```

Comment: If you have more than one it's not really a singleton anymore is it? `static MyClass<MyInputClass> instance(input);` means only one object is created the first time it is called, after that the line has no effect. If you can describe more of how you plan to use this it will probably improve the advice.

Comment: Is there a connection between the input string and `MyInputClass`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I want to make the input optional, so that if there's no input, then it will have a single instance per MyInputClass (eg a child class of MyInputClass). But there's another use case in which for the same MyInputClass, I want a different instance per input.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a singleton, you want a flyweight https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Flyweight_pattern&oldid=1096803725

Comment: Maybe use a std::map or std::unordered_map to map the string to the instance

Comment: Is this the static keyword at work? Yes. In your code the parameter will only be used for the first call for each instantiation - each `MyInputClass` you instantiated the template with. It's not really the SIngleton pattern. I think you're trying for maybe instance pooling.

Comment: A `std::unordered_map` mapping the strings to the appropriate handler class could be appropriate, but everything in the map must have a compatible type, and `MyClass<Base*>` and `MyClass<Derived*>` are not close enough. They are two different `MyClass`s. You'd need to flip things around so that you get `std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClassBase*>` and all of the `MyClass<Derived>`s derive from `MyClassBase`. That gets a bit convoluted, but there are opportunities to simplify.

Comment: This calls for the "Running Object Table" pattern, where consumers can fetch existing objects by name.  And yes, `unordered_map` as @user4581301 mentioned can be a good data structure to build your Running Object Table from.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to maintain a (singleton) collection of your instances, that differentiate between them based on `std::string` argument. As it was already stated in the comment section `std::unordered_map` looks like the best candidate for such a task. Be advised, though, that you also want to ensure thread safety when accessing such a collection because it can change on the fly.

With all that in mind, here is how I would implement such a factory:

```
class Singleton {
    const std::string input;
    
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(const std::string &_input): input{ _input } {};
    
    template<typename T, typename B>
    friend class std::pair; // in order to access the private constructor when emplacing
public:
    
    static Singleton& sharedInstance(std::string input = "") {
        static std::shared_mutex access_mutex;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, Singleton> instance_map;
        
        std::shared_lock lock { access_mutex };
        if (instance_map.find(input) == instance_map.end()) {
            
            lock.unlock();
            std::unique_lock unique_lock { access_mutex };
            instance_map.try_emplace(input, input);
        }
        
        return instance_map.at(input);
    }
};
```

In the client code it can be used like this (`ins1` and `ins2` refer to the same instance here):

```
int main() {
    const auto& default_ins = Singleton::sharedInstance();
    const auto& ins1 = Singleton::sharedInstance("arg");
    const auto& ins2 = Singleton::sharedInstance("arg");
    const auto& ins3 = Singleton::sharedInstance("arg2");
    
    return 0;
}
```